# C# - Add reference for both MS Excel 12.0 object library and MS Excel 14.0 object library?

Tags: c#, com-interop, office-interop, excel-interop

I have recently developed a small tool that uses `Microsoft.Office.Excel.Interop`, and according to my References folder I have added the reference to the Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library. I should also mention that I have MS Office 2010 on my machine, so the tool works just fine there.

However I have a client user that is trying to install the tool on his machine (apparently he has MS Office 2003 installed) and is getting an error message.

I was wondering, would there be any issues if I download the Microsoft Excel 12.0 Object Library and also add its Reference into my tool so that I have references to both, MS Excel 14 and MS Excel 12? ... would doing that even make sense?

Again, I'm fairly new to .NET and my programming experience is purely empirical, as in no school. Just a heads up in case this is a stupid question.

**EDIT:**

I found something that seems to solve this problem. I had my client download the file from this link: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3508

Then just follow the instructions at the bottom, and this apparently solved the problem. He was able to install the tool and run it without issues.

Comment: you can try Aliasing the namespace this way you won't run into version conflicts.. and or Copy the specific version into the Bin folder, or Gac it on that particular Machine..

Comment: @DJKRAZE: Thank you! Apparently running this file also solves the problem... http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3508

Answer (score 3):

The best solution I have found is to use a virtual machine as a build machine that has the oldest version of the office Interop libraries installed that I care to support.  I did run into a number of issues trying to develop with multiple interop versions on my development machine.

Microsoft does provide guidance on building clients for multiple office versions but I found that too cumbersome for my particular use case.

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?kbid=244167

You also might consider skipping Interop entirely by using an alternative library, such as the open source EP Plus.  I have not personally tried that one yet, but it looks promising.

http://epplus.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks Eric! I'm going to explore your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

There are some differences between the versions of the Interops. If you will use some members that were added in the newer version then the older versions won't work. For example here is a list of what all was added in Interop version 14:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194938(v=office.14).aspx

If you use any of those your application won't work in older versions since these members were not available in older versions.